# Python Imports from self-created Project Directory Structure

Tags: python-3.x, import, directory-structure

I have created a simple python project, which has following directory structure:

```
> my-project
    |--> processors
        |--> data-processor.py
        |--> process-customizations.py
    |--> utilities
        |--> log_utility.py
        |--> helper_functions.py
```

Here, `my-project` is the "project root" and while development, in VS, I marked `pythonpath` as `my-project` and I could run my scripts perfectly.

My `data-processor.py` needs to import from all other 3 files as mentioned, for which I'm using following statement to import:

```
from utilities import helper_functions
```

etc.

Now, I want this simple project to work on any Linux OS, through command-line. How can I achieve it? As of now, I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "my-project/processors/data-processor.py", line 16, in <module>
    from utilities import helper_functions 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utilities'
```

upon execution of:

```
python3 path/to/my-project/processors/data-processor.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [package relative imports](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#package-relative-imports). So in `data-processor.py`, it would be

```
from ..utilities import helper_functions
```